# Чи правильно виробники використовують слово "сліди"?

Tags: значення-слів

Питання скоріш за все суто побутове. Як звичайного споживача мене зацікавила фраза, яку використовують майже всі виробники на обгортках своїх виробів - "містить сліди кунжуту", "містить сліди арахісу" тощо. У якому сенсі тут використовується слово "сліди", і чи взагалі це слово підходить за змістом у таких словосполученнях?
Як взагалі існує таке поняття як "слід якогось продукту"...
На просторі інтернету я не знайшла пояснення цьому...

Звичайно зрозуміло що, наприклад: робили на заводі шоколад з кунжутом, а потім пустили партію без нього, і з обладнання можуть потрапити "сліди кунжуту"... Але ж з точки зору мови, значення слів - як це можливо?

Comment: Мабуть, калька з англійського «trace (amount, concentration)» (це не відповідь не Ваше запитання, просто пояснюю «сам до себе»).

Comment: Колись давно у війську нам готували кашу з м'ясом, і зі зрозумілих причин ми називали її кашею з привітом від м'яса. Здається, що суть та сама. Це теж не відповідь.

Answer (score 2):

У Словнику української мови в 11 т. знаходимо, серед інших, таке значення слова слід:

> 3. Те, що уціліло, збереглося від руйнування, нищення, загибелі і т. ін. 
>      //  Рештки чого-небудь на чомусь. В кутку чорна дошка з слідами крейди, в кінці хати стіл (Леся Українка, III, 1952, 572)

У тому ж словнику знаходимо тлумачення слова *рештки*:

> РЕ́ШТКИ, ток, мн.
>
> 1. Сліди, залишки чого-небудь.

Отже, стосовно частин продуктів, що залишилися від попереднього виробництва, доречніше було би вжити іменник *рештки*, бо відповідне значення в нього - на першому місці. Але іменник *сліди* не суперечить нормі.

Comment: [Дехто](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/суперечити-суперечність/) вважає, що «протирічити» краще замінити на «суперечити». Хоча наскільки «протирічити» справді виходить за межі норми я не досліджував.

Comment: @Saha, дякую, дійсно, слова протирічити навіть немає в жодному словнику